# How to create a patch from the diff between two patches

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have made modifications in my local SVN working copy, created a patch, and submitted that patch to the repository maintainer.

The repository maintainer merged that patch in, but my access to that server is down for another week (my VPN token expired and getting a new one will take some time) so until it's back up again I can't update my working copy.

In the meantime, I've made further modifications to my local working directory and have created a second patch.

How can I get the difference between the two patches as a .patch file to send the repo maintainer to apply my latest changes?

Alternatively, is there a way I can apply an SVN update to my local repo in an offline state (e.g. files emailed to me).

Note: I'm on Windows, using TortoiseSVN but will try any tools that get me to where I need to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Linux (even using [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)), you can simply create another patch and then use the [`interdiff`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/interdiff) command which shows differences between two diff files.

```
interdiff patch1 patch2
```

In Ubuntu, `interdiff` can be installed using:

```
sudo apt install patchutils
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure your goal can't be reached with TortoiseSVN's GUI. I don't have a proper environment with me right now, but this is what I would try:

- Copy the complete working copy, and name it `old`.
- Revert changes in `old` working copy.
- Apply your existing patch to 'old' working copy.
- Run `svn diff` command from command prompt targeting these two working copies.
- Edit if needed the resulting .diff file so that it appears to represent the difference between two revisions of the same working copy, instead of two different working copies.

New versions of TortoiseSVN have the `svn` command available in command prompt. I hope you have it available as well.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. The SVN diff command sees that both folders have the same revision and it just dumps the pending changes to the diff file.